# What is CompileC?

Tags: xcode

I'm amazed a simple Google search didn't answer this... I know it's something used by XCode but I can't run it or get a man page from the command line either.

What does it do and where can I find information?

Comment: It appears to be the compilation step within `xcodebuild`, but as you say there appears to be no documentation available.  Can I ask what it is about CompileC that you need to know?

Comment: I'm trying to understand the XCode build process compared to command-line, therefore need to know what the steps do.

Comment: Also I'm not sure it is the compilation step, because XCode also calls gcc (gcc-4.2 in my case). Unless CompileC calls gcc...

Answer (score 13):

CompileC is a logged representation of an internal function for xcodebuild. It is a source of basic information about the compilation in the build.log file. For a simple terminal app with a main.m class, information after CompileC indicates:

- the object file (main.o, temporarily stored in a hashed directory during the xcodebuild process)
- the method file (main.m)
- compilation mode (normal - I don't know the other options - anyone?)
- architecture (X86_64)
- language (objective-c)
- the compiler (com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler)

You cannot access CompileC from the command line directly, but you can have lots of control over the Xcode build process from the command line if you wish:

```
man xcodebuild
```